# Extract text from specifica pdf area in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, pdf, data-conversion

Is there a way to extract part of the pdf document and export in text file?
I have an invoice sent me by pdf and I would like to have a way to "detect" the area to convert into text and store the value into my db.

I found some scripts that converts all the document into text file but it's all the document, not a specific part.

Any idea?

I attach the pdf sample area [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkxSn.jpg)

What i would like to have is only the yellow part. Possible?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to extract all the text and then look for patterns using RegEx. For instance, you should be able to look for the header rows of the table as a start, and then maybe the Sub Total/Tax/Total area for an end.

Comment: thanks for your replies. The fact is that the document can change layout, for this reason I supposed to allow the user to raw an area where to extract texts... Possibile?

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks. Your suggestion is interesting. Can we have a try-demo? Just to better understand... thanks in advance

Comment: To do a demo we'd need an actual PDF, but I personally unfortunately don't have time for that. But start small, run a PDF through a text extraction tool like pdftotext and get everything, then maybe update your question or create a new one

Comment: @ChrisHaas I think that the better way is to allow the user to draw a rectangle around the text he want to convert, and then ask the code to convert to text... what do you think?

Comment: @KJ I know that he can copy and paste from pdf. The procedure should be automated... so without the user interaction

Comment: "I think that the better way is to allow the user to draw a rectangle around the text" - "The procedure should be automated... so without the user interaction" - these two statements are at odds with each other.

Comment: @ChrisHaas when i say "automated" I mean that the script then must read in the rectangular area drawn by the user

Comment: @ChrisHaas sorry for my mistake

Comment: If you're open for a non-free version you may check out [this demo](https://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-extractor/demos/extract-words-by-a-specific-location/) of the SetaPDF-Extractor component which seems to be very near to your requirements (PS: I'm related to Setasign).